# Laravel 5.2 Emails not sending out

Tags: laravel, email, registration

Trying to send an activation mail after registering on the website (using the Auth Controller).

Here's the code of my **controller:**

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $data['activation_code'] = str_random(20);

    return User::create([
        'firstname' => $data['firstname'],
        'lastname' => $data['lastname'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'activation_code' => $data['activation_code'],
    ]);

    Mail::send('emails.register', $data, function($message) use ($data)
    {
        $message->from('info@foodtruckbestellen.be', "Foodtruckbestellen.be");
        $message->subject("Welkom bij foodtruckbestellen.be");
        $message->to($data['email']);
    });
}
```

and here's the code of my **email view:**

```
<h1>Hi {{ $data['firstname'] }}</h1>
<p>
    Link = <a href="http://192.168.33.10/register/activate?code={{ $data['verification_code'] }}'">CLICK ME</a>
</p>
```

Part of my **.env**:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mail
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

The user get's saved in the DB without any problem, but my email isn't sending out. I don't receive any errors, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Can you check your system's mailer see if there is any log?

Comment: @weigreen I'm just on my localhost

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup your .env file. Just register at mailtrap and copy/paste the the username and password from mailtrap to the .env file.

Edit:

```
        Mail::send('email.register', ['data' => $data], function ($message) use ($data) {
        $message->from('info@foodtruckbestellen.be', 'Foodtruckbestellen.be');
        $message->to($data['email']);
        $message->subject('Welkom bij foodtruckbestellen.be);
    });
```

Try this code. I think you must use `use` and `$data` must be inside array. Hope this was helpful.

Comment: I just did that but mailtrap doesn't seem to receive any emails in the inbox

Comment: Did it help? @NicolasDecroos

Comment: Nope, still don't receive anything